# binary install in google container optimized OS

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, google-container-optimized-os

As it is the Linux version of OS, I tried firing, hoping that would work

```
apt-get install jq
```

But it says apt-get: command not found.

How I can install new binaries as I wanted to add some extra logic in the startup script which required few extra libs to be installed first.

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Container OS is locked down. You are prohibited from installing programs. Create a container and run the command in the container.

> Container-Optimized OS does not include a package manager; as such,
> you'll be unable to install software packages directly on an instance.
> However, you can use CoreOS toolbox to install and run debugging and
> admin tools in an isolated container.

[Container-Optimized OS Overview](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits)

Comment: Yes I can understand this, but I wanted to know how I can have a modification to startup script for containerized OS VM where I need to validate few logic and sent some messages to pubsub if those conditions met...

Comment: Your original question has been answered. Create a new question. There are many options for sending messages via Pub/Sub. That is an entire topic to itself. However, you cannot change the Container OS startup script. If you want that level of control you will need to launch your own Compute Engine instance, install Docker, etc.

Comment: You are saying that instead of using "create-with-container" for compute instance, we need to deploy normal VM and install docker for our deployment, so we can install what ever we want

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Answer (score 5):

https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox
You can use toolbox to install the package

Answer (score 0):

You can [specify a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#running_startup_scripts) through the metadata server. The script would be run at boot time.